Let a,b,c be positive real numbers. Prove asymmetric inequality $\frac{1}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{1}{(a+c)^2}+\frac{16}{(b+c)^2} \ge \frac{6}{ab + bc + ca}$

Let a,b,c be positive real numbers.
Prove $$\frac{1}{(a+b)^2} + \frac{1}{(a+c)^2}+\frac{16}{(b+c)^2} \ge
 \frac{6}{ab + bc + ca}$$

The equality holds when $b=c$ and $a=0$. I tried to use the identity $(a+b+c)(ab+bc+ac) = (a+b)(b+c)(a+c) + abc$  along side $abc \ge 0$, the inequality after that is still correct but I don't have any ideas after that.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, an Approach0 search results in the AoPS threads In connection with Iran 1996, Inequality, inequality & Nice inequality.

The inequality is equivalent to
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{a+c}\right)^2+\dfrac{16}{(b+c)^2} \geq \dfrac{6}{ab+bc+ca}+\dfrac{2}{(a+b)(a+c)}$$
for positive reals $a,b,c$.
Now, using the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$\left(\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{a+c}\right)^2+\dfrac{16}{(b+c)^2} \geq \dfrac{8}{b+c}\left(\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{a+c}\right)$$
and since
$$\dfrac{2}{(a+b)(a+c)} \leq \dfrac{2}{ab+bc+ca}$$
it is enough to prove that
$$\dfrac{8}{b+c}\left(\dfrac{1}{a+b}+\dfrac{1}{a+c}\right) \geq \dfrac{8}{ab+bc+ca}$$
which is equivalent to
$$(2a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) \geq (a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$$
which is obvious since
$$(2a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca)\geq (a+b+c)(ab+bc+ca) \geq (a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$$
hence completing the proof.
